# Get Max Number from list

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to get the max number from a list using Maybe & Just  and recursion. I have figured out the recursion part but not able to understand the correct syntax to use

**Haskell Code**..

```
Max :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
Max [_] = []
Max (x:xs)
    | x > (Max xs) = Just x
    | otherwise = Max xs
```

**Input**

```
Max [1,2,78]
Max [-99,-12,-37]
```

**Compilation Error message**

```
  *Main> :l max.hs
  [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( max.hs, interpreted )

  max.hs:2:14: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Int' with actual type `[a0]'
* In the expression: []
  In an equation for `Max': Max [_] = []
 |
 2 | Max [_] = []
 |              ^^

 max.hs:4:16: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Maybe Int'
* In the second argument of `(>)', namely `(Max xs)'
  In the expression: x > (Max xs)
  In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                 an equation for `Max':
    x > (Max xs)
 |
 4 |         | x > (Max xs) = Just x
 |                ^^^^^^^^^
 Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Function names must begin with a lower-case letter, so you cannot name your function `Max`.

Comment: See also [maximum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.4.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html#v:maximum) from the delightful monoid-extras package.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax isn't *that* important. What's more important is to understand
why you would want to return a `Maybe Int` instead of an `Int` in the
first place.

The integers are a totally ordered set, but there is no *minimum*
(an element that is less or equal to any other element). Therefore,
if the return type were simply `Int`, one wouldn't know what to return for an empty list.
Conceptually, one would like to return something like a "negative 
infinity", but this is not a proper integer.

Instead, we can do the following. We define a new totally ordered set
`Maybe Int`, where

- `Just n` corresponds to ordinary integer `n`
- `Nothing` corresponds to the "negative infinity"

When comparing `Just n` and `Just m`, we simply compare `n` and `m`.
When comparing `Just n` with `Nothing`, `Just n` should always be
greater than `Nothing`. That is, the `Nothing` becomes an artificially added
"negative infinity"-minimum element.

Now, since the list datatype has two constructors (empty list and 
a head element `cons`ed onto a tail), we need two cases:

- If the list is empty, return the artificial "negative infinity" element
- If the list is non-empty with head `x`, compare `Just x` to the maximum of the tail.

When comparing, we have to distinguish between the cases that maximum of the tail
can be either `Nothing` or `Just m`.

Putting it all together, we obtain something like this:

```
findMax :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
findMax [] = Nothing
findMax (x:xs) = 
  case (findMax xs) of
    Nothing -> Just x
    Just m -> if x > m then Just x else Just m

main = print $ show $ findMax [22, 23, 52, 21, 33, 71, 15, 18, 34]
```

Note that I renamed `Max` to `findMax`, because function names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several issues to address in your code:

(1) function names usually start with lowercase in Haskell

(2) considering (1), we may not want to overwrite the `max` from Prelude

(3) the first line matches something still in the list: `Max [_] = []` means if `_` is the largest, we'll get a wrong answer :)

(4) the line in (3) is returning `[]`, which is  not a Maybe type. Return `Nothing` instead

(5) we need a "lowest" number to match on. Andrey's answer offers a nice conceptual alternative. I've gone for the more dirty but quaint `-1/0` for a very low number.

Hope this helps!

```hs
import Data.Maybe

myMax :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
myMax [] = Nothing
myMax (x:xs)
    -- we need fromMaybe here because we can't `>` with Nothing
    | x > fromMaybe (floor(-1/0)) (myMax xs) = Just x
    | otherwise = myMax xs

main = print(myMax [1,2,78])
```

Comment: It would be cleaner to use `minBound` instead of `floor (-1/0)`. You could also consider `| Just x > myMax xs`, though this is perhaps a bit opaque and could easily hide a bug if one weren't careful to check that this did the right thing when `myMax xs` were `Nothing` -- and in particular `Just x < myMin xs` wouldn't be right for an analogous `myMin` implementation. Also, because you are recomputing `myMax xs` in both branches of the guard, this implementation is exponential time in the worst case -- quite inefficient indeed! Use a `where` block to alleviate this.

Comment: @DanielWagner thank you very much for your helpful comments! My main mission was to align with what seemed the OP's intention code-wise. I didn't know about minBound, will look up, tx!

Comment: @DanielWagner `maybe True (x >) (myMax xs)` has 1) no reliance on either `Bounded` or undefined math, 2) an explicit case for when `myMax xs` is `Nothing`, and 3) an analogous `myMin` implementation

Comment: @Fox Yes, that or similar is my preferred way, but it seems the person writing this answer was explicitly trying to avoid it for some reason (see property (5) in the answer above).